# Is the Christoffel connection in 2D a total derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions

Can someone comment on my following calculation? Consider the 2D metric $\sigma^{ab}$ and its associated Christoffel connection

$$\Gamma^{a}_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{ap}(\partial_b\sigma_{pc}+\partial_c\sigma_{pb}-\partial_p\sigma_{bc}).$$
Due to symmetry of $b \leftrightarrow c$ in first two terms, for 2D dimensions I can use
$$\partial_b\sigma_{pc}+\partial_c\sigma_{pb} =\sigma_{bc}\sigma^{qr}\partial_r\sigma_{qp} \equiv \sigma_{bc}\partial^q\sigma_{qp}$$
since, $\sigma_{bc}$ is the only basic two-index symmetric tensor structure you can write in 2D. Using this in the above, we can see that
$$\Gamma^{a}_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{ap}(\sigma_{bc}\partial^q\sigma_{qp}-\partial_p\sigma_{bc})\\= -\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_{bc}\sigma_{qp}\partial^q\sigma^{ap}+\sigma^{ap}\partial_p\sigma_{bc})\\=-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_{bc}\partial_p\sigma^{ap}+\sigma^{ap}\partial_p\sigma_{bc})\\=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_p(\sigma^{ap}\sigma_{bc}).$$

Comment: Your calculation seems to rely on an unstated assumption that $\sigma_{ab}$ is $\epsilon_{ab}$, which isn’t true. If you didn’t assume that, how did you get the first equality in the second equation?

Comment: @Ghoster No. I did not assume that. I 'reasoned' that due to the symmetry in the $b$ and $c$ index in 2D I can write the LHS as $\sigma_{bc} \lambda_p$ because that is the only basic symmetric tensor structure you have in 2D. $\lambda_p$ I later determined through trace. Can you please tell me if my reasoning is flawed?

Comment: Yes, I think it is flawed. The $bc$ symmetry doesn’t imply that $b$ and $c$ have to be two indices on the same two-index tensor.

Comment: @Ghoster I see. I think you make a valid point. Can you please put that in the answer so that I may select that and bring closure to this question?

Comment: I’ll let you write your own answer if you want. Personally, I think you should accept Pipe’s counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple counterexample. Consider the following metric in $(t,x)$ coordinates
\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = -a(x) dt^{2} + dx^{2},
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{tx}^{t} = \frac{1}{2}g^{tt}\partial_{x}g_{tt} = \frac{a'}{2a} \ne -\frac{1}{2}\partial_{t}(g^{tt}g_{tx}) = 0.
\end{equation}